# Spark memory limit exceeded issue

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

i have a job that run on spark and is written in scala im using spark RDD. because of the expensive group by operations i get this error:
 `Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 22.4 GB of 22 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead`.
 i increased memory over head but i get the same. i use 10 machines of r4.xlarge. i tried using r4.2xlarge and even r4.4xlarge but also same error. the data is im testing on is 5GB gzipped data( almost 50 unzipped of data and almost 6 million record).

some configurations:

`spark.executor.memory`: 20480M
`spark.driver.memory`: 21295M
`spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead`: 2g
`spark.executor.instances`: 10

And the code looks like this:

```
val groupedEntitiesRDD = datasetRDD 
  .groupBy(_.entityId) 
  .map({ case (key, valueIterator) => key -> valueIterator.toList }) 
  .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK) 

val deduplicatedRDD = groupedEntitiesRDD 
  .flatMap({ case (_, entities) => deduplication(entities) }) 

def deduplication(entities: List[StreamObject[JsValue]]): List[StreamObject[JsValue]] = { 
  entities 
    .groupBy(_.deduplicationKey) 
    .values 
    .map(duplicates => duplicates.maxBy(_.processingTimestamp.toEpochSecond)) 
    .toList 
}
```

Comment: What version of Spark are you using?

Comment: spark version:  2.1.1

Comment: And how have you configured your memory settings? How much memory on each executor, how much overhead and how many executors?

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt i added the info to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience and from what I have read in the release notes of Spark 2.x, one needs to allocate a lot more off heap memory (`spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead`) than in Spark 1.x.

You have only assigned 2G to memoryOverhead and 20GB memory. I believe you would get better results if you change that to say 8G memoryOverhead and 14GB executor memory.

Should you still still run into memory issues (like actual OOMs being thrown), you will need to look into data skews. Especially `groupBy` operations will frequently cause serious data skews.

One final thing, you write that you use `RDDs` - I hope you mean `DataFrames` or `DataSets`? `RDDs` has very low performance with `groupBy` (see for instance [this](https://blog.knoldus.com/2015/06/19/shufflling-and-repartitioning-of-rdds-in-apache-spark/) blog post for reason why) so if you are on `RDDs` you should use `reduceByKey` instead. BUT essentially you should use DataFrames (or DataSets) instead, where `groupBy` is indeed the right way to go.

**EDIT!**

You asked in a comment how to convert `groupBy` to `reduceByKey`. You can do that like this:

```
datasetRDD
  .map{case(entityID, streamObject) => (entityID, List(streamObject))}
  .reduceByKey(_++_)
  .flatMap{case(_, entities) => deduplication(entities)
```

You haven't specified the data structure of these entities, but it looks like you are looking for some max value and in effect throwing away unwanted data. That should be build into the `reduceByKey`-operation, such that you filter away unnecessary data while reducing.

Comment: Thanks. i will try to change the configuration for executor memory and memory overhead and test again. regarding choosing RDD this article: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/42027/rdd-vs-dataframe-vs-sparksql.html says that its the fastest for many aggregations operations(including group by)

Comment: Yes, but if you read the code for the "groupBy" operation on the RDD, you will notice that they use `reduceByKey` ;-)

Comment: And I mean read the code from the article you refer to - they use `reduceByKey` and not `groupBy`.

Comment: ok thanks. do you have an example of using group by with data frames. or how to use reduce instead of data frames. i have a deduplication application and in this case reduce can not be used instead of group by

Comment: `reduceByKey` is a function on `RDDs` and it can ALWAYS be used instead of the `groupBy`-function. If you post your code, I can help you transform it to use `reduceByKey` instead of `groupBy`

Comment: ```val groupedEntitiesRDD = datasetRDD
      .groupBy(_.entityId)
      .map({ case (key, valueIterator) => key -> valueIterator.toList })
      .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)```

    ```val deduplicatedRDD = groupedEntitiesRDD
      .flatMap({ case (_, entities) => deduplication(entities) }) ```      ```def deduplication(entities: List[StreamObject[JsValue]]): List[StreamObject[JsValue]] = {
    entities
      .groupBy(_.deduplicationKey)
      .values
      .map(duplicates => duplicates.maxBy(_.processingTimestamp.toEpochSecond))
      .toList
  }```

Comment: here: ```.map{case(entityID, streamObject) => (entityID, List(streamObject))}``` dud you assume that dataset records are already grouped by? otherwise why mapping ```case(entityID, streamObject)``` where it is a StreamObject

Comment: No, it is not grouped at that point. The mapping is creating a list with one element (the streamObject). The following `reduceByKey` does the actual grouping by aggregating all elements into one list. Perhaps it would be easier if you read up on how reduceByKey works.

Comment: Thanks Glennie, using reduceByKey making much better performance than groupBy!